# How to implement a spec and prove it using kami?

Tags: coq, bluespec

I’m a beginner to kami and coq. I’m trying to implement a spec and prove the same using kami. Can anyone please tell me how to start with the coding part,how to write code for the implementation and spec in kami?

Comment: IIANM Kami (and Coq itself) is a research project so expect a steep learning curve. On the other hand the rewards of climbing it will be super :)

I'm not familiar with Kami but the first thing that comes to my mind is that it is indeed likely a very unstable research project, so my first step would be to get in touch directly with the developers, as IMHO your question is a bit out of scope for SO.